# Rails - To use polymorphism or not for performance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, polymorphism

I have 9 models in my applications that use a paperclip column for profile photo and cover photo.

I have 2 options (at least from my limited understanding)

1. Have a polymorphic model `ProfilePicture` that is associated with the other 9 models.
2. Add the fields for profile picture and cover photo in each of the models.

In total, the 9 models have around 30M records.

Would it be better for performance to use polymorphism or go ahead with the normal workflow. Or is there a better option that I am missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Performance, while being important, isn't always the most crucial aspect. You are in theory going to have to duplicate the columns and logic to 9 different models. If you take the polymorphic route, you will have logic in a single place, but then have to load the associated record for every user. I would go polymorphic and cache the associated with the user. You could use something like [IdentityCache](https://github.com/Shopify/identity_cache) to do this. As long as you index the `picturable_id` and `picturable_type` on the `ProfilePicture` table the lookups will be extremely fast.